# Why a call to a consteval from object constructor is not constant expression?

Tags: c++, constructor, consteval

I have the `consteval` function shown below:

```
template <std::size_t text_length>
consteval std::size_t text_id(const char(&a_text)[text_length])
{
    std::size_t result{text_length};
    for (const auto &c : a_text)
    {
        result ^= c;
        result <<= ((c % 7u) + 1u);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works as expected on the places where a compile-time value is expected:

```
template <auto x>
auto v = x;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    constexpr auto id = text_id("test");

    switch (argc)
    {
        // No problem
        case text_id("test"):
            std::cout << v<text_id("test")>; // No problem either
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But [it doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADMXKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BeqnpjgIhYZEsMXFmAKy2mPaFDEIETMQE2T5%2BAXaYDpmNzQTFEdGxCUkKTS1tuWMTA6FDZSNVAJS2qF7EyOwc5vGhyN5YANQm8W5O48SYrKfYJhoAgvcPBJgsyQavJ2fj6CAg6QAXpgAPoEI6vVQEEH0IwEBC3Z5oBjjTAANzER1%2B/yBoPBkOheHQEGR4yOyAQzQg5gAbEwwZgocsTJULASYYxgPCWQARZmPEwAdisAo0AE5sQC8MCwUcrgovLQCEK2YzobCuQjBTzTiKnuL%2BMQjiSBGSmF4iCczDTkEcQEd6QT%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%2BNDTGYywzCiJTam6eoXAYdxPHaPRgnmUpyjyNIMgEKY/CSfJzoYQZjpGMYNp6AQ%2BkmPbphqOpelme7hjiGZ%2BkuvQQJaP7FgB1YFDYrY9DyzBEuKiiOCo0gaLohiOFUAAOGlZppSQjmAZBbXMzCzGNJirEsUgjlwQgSCtRJaY8XT6CNTjll4HiAuWAShJEiShdEqTkdktH5MxpSVLU3nSE0xAQHWAhkgtAyTTZx7AnwIgAY6lrxHa/hBEUFR1DC%2BHEdIarMuSIryMouSwsxryLVV8FUCoI4cbxgmiZJjMuHJynUE1jmzESLnZa0PnSEE0TBeFiTpI4cX0d4KXbBlnmY4djgzCdjHFOjvjSGi4h0mcSQgA%3D%3D%3D) if I put it on an object constructor:

```
struct S
{
    template <std::size_t size>
    constexpr S(const char (&text)[size]) :
        id{text_id(text)}
    {}

    std::size_t id;
};

int main()
{
/*
error: 'text' is not a constant expression
        id{text_id(text)}
           ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
*/
    constexpr S s("test");
    static_assert(text_id("test") == s.id);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: `text` is not necessary to be constant.

Comment: I know, but it is on the context of my test.

Comment: you simply cannot do it, call a consteval function with potentially non-consteval value make little sense, if you want, you can declare the constructor as consteval. or the function constexpr.

Comment: Hold on! I didn't know that `S::S` can be marked as `consteval`! that totally works! :)

Comment: `constexpr` allows evaluation at run time while `consteval` requires compile time evaluation. So `constexpr` needs to generate run time code for the function with an unknown `text` even if you never call it. The call could be in another compilation unit.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `consteval` function with `constexpr` function's parameter, since it may be non-constant.

```
consteval int bar(int){
    return 1;
}

constexpr int foo(int s){
    return bar(s); // error
}
```

---

You can change `S::S` to `consteval` or change `text_id` to `constexpr`.

Comment: btw, call `constexpr` function with `consteval` function's parameter is also valid. (so `consteval S::S` and `constexpr text_id` also works)